# How to create a vector of Matrices in python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

In my code i have calculated multiple flow map with respect to time and want to store in one list. This is what i want to do in may code

[image]

Comment: Clarify -do you want a `list` or a 3d `array`?

Comment: You can simply add them to a list like this `my_list = [np_array_1, np_array_2, ...]` . If you want to stack them into another numpy array you could have a look at [numpy.dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html). If this doesn't solve your question, post some code of what you tried and where it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before entering your time loop, create an empty list:

```
listOfFlowMaps = []
```

Then, after creating your flow map:

```
flowmap = np.array([...]) # your flow map
listOfFlowMaps.append(flowmap) # add the flow map to the list
```